# Creating a mobile-first site that works on IE8 (desktop)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design, media-queries

I am currently working on a website that uses media-queries to deliver different layouts to mobile and desktop users (i.e. 2 cases). Following the mobile first approach I first style for the mobile view and then use media-queries for styles that create the desktop view.

This works fine, except of course in browsers that do not support media-queries. IE8 is to be supported, so obviously it just ignores everything I amended for desktop and just shows the mobile view.

The one thing I came up with was creating a dedicated stylesheet for IE that contains everything that went into the media-query, but this seems to be a very clumsy way to do it, as I have to update it manually.

This must be a rather common situation - what do you consider best practice here?

Comment: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. I use it all the time for designing the mobile-first websites.

Previously I used to use [css3-mediaqueries.js](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) but the link is dead now. So you may be able to use it if you can get it from somewhere.

I do not use 'css3-mediaqueries.js' now because if you have any `css` in your file targeting only Firefox browser, then 'css3-mediaqueries.js' will crash and won't work.

You can use [Respond.js](http://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). Unlike css3-mediaqueries.js respond.js works perfect for all browsers.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm checking out respond.js right now.